# Is it bad practice to catch the Exception class instead of Exception sub-classes?

Tags: java

I have a method which throws subclasses of Exception. If I am performing the same catch functionality for each sub-class of Exception that's causght is it bad practice to just catch the Exceptions class or should I catch each exception individually ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's bad practice, because it makes the catch block catch runtime exceptions that shouldn't be caught.

If you use Java 7, you can use

```
catch (SomeException | SomeOtherException | YetAnotherException e) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I can understand why it's bad to just catch the lowest level `Exception` class, but would there be any problems if all of the possible exceptions have a common parent, (that isn't `Exception`) such as `IOException`?

Comment: @JB Nizet should runtime exceptions not be caught ?

Comment: @user470184: runtime exceptions indicate bugs in the code. You don't want your method to return something meaningful if the code has bugs. Instead, you want the method to fail fast, in order to identify the bug and fix it. Suppose your exceptions indicate that you don't have a cancer. Would you like your cancer to go unnoticed if the code has a bug and throws a NullPointerException?

Comment: @user470184 You can catch runtime exceptions for the same reasons you catch any other Exception; you plan to do something with it. Usually you might catch one if you think you can recover from whatever may have caused it. You shouldn't catch exceptions just for the sake of catching them, though.

Comment: @NickHartung: if it's meaningful to do what the catch block does for any kind of IOException, then no problem in catching IOException.

Answer (score 2):

It is always suggested to catch possible exceptions (sub classes) than just catching all exceptions using all in one `Exception` catch block. Here is one [reference](http://code.google.com/p/solidbase/wiki/ExceptionHandlingGuideline).

Answer (score 1):

If you can do the same functionality for any unexpected execptions (runtime execeptions, for example) thrown by your code, it is fine.

Otherwise, I recommend catching the sub-classes.

Consider what would happen if some part of your code threw a `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 1):

At some point, exceptions **have** to be handled. So there hopefully is a place in an application that handles (catches) all exceptions. Usually, this is a place where unexpected exceptions are caught to prevent complete application crashes and instead provide some path of recovery, along with some excusing message to the user. In general, in your classes, handle the expected failures and trust the contract your classes and methods provide to the caller. For example, in a method that fetches a record by an ID string from a database, do only catch the SQL exceptions, as your contract may clearly say that a null ID is not allowed. Throw back the bad input exceptions back to the caller, else you may end up validating user input at the wrong level.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is bad practice to squelch exceptions by catching the Exception class. Exceptions are designed to transmit problem reports to the handler, and doing this could possibly hide a serious error.