# Is there a Sonar rule to detect "catch Exception"? If not, why not?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I think my Google skills are failing me. I can't find a Squid rule in Sonarqube which detects the use of `catch (Exception ex)` instead of catching specific sub-classes.

Although there may be times this is required, I thought it was generally regarded as poor form
[Is it bad practice to catch the Exception class instead of Exception sub-classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752104/is-it-bad-practice-to-catch-the-exception-class-instead-of-exception-sub-classes#) so am surprised. Is there a reason it's (apparently) missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use:

checkstyle:com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.coding.IllegalCatchCheck

It's not squid, but it does work really well for us and hopefully will work for you also.

Comment: Thanks I also found pmd:AvoidCatchingGenericException . I'm surprised there doesn't seem to be a Squid replacement though - maybe @Fabrice - SonarSource Team  could comment?

Comment: @Disco3 see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This exact one is not released yet but should be available in next release of the java plugin (version 3.6)
see specification of rule  : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-2221 and implementation ticket : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1253